# Jupyter notebook crashing for scikit TSNE dimensionality reduction

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter

I am using Jupyter notebook and python 2.7 from anaconda. I have an approximately 250,000 dimensional data set which I need to compress to n lower dimensions. I am using scikit TSNE. When running the TSNE for `n=5` or `n=10`, it works fine. But when I go to `n=50` or more, the following message is shown: `"The kernel appears to have died."` There is no error message displayed. What is the problem? Is it due to a memory overload? Should I run the code in the terminal as a script rather than in Jupyter?

My TSNE function:

```
def tsne_to_n_dimensions(n):
    start=timer()
    #tsne
    print diff_df.shape
    tsne = sklearn.manifold.TSNE(n_components=n,verbose=2)
    data_nd_tsne =tsne.fit_transform(diff_df)

    calculate stuff from data_nd_tsne        
    return stuff
```

And diff_df is a global panda data frame

I have gone through [this](https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl/issues/273)
and [this](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1178) but couldn't find a solution

Comment: You can track how much memory the process is using by using [top](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html). Might be worth taking note of the docs for tSNE from `scikit`: "It is highly recommended to use another dimensionality reduction method (e.g. PCA for dense data or TruncatedSVD for sparse data) to reduce the number of dimensions to a reasonable amount (e.g. 50) if the number of features is very high. This will suppress some noise and speed up the computation of pairwise distances between samples. For more tips see Laurens van der Maaten’s FAQ [2]."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution using [`python-bhtsne`](https://github.com/dominiek/python-bhtsne) which is also an implementation of *Barnes-Hut's t-Distributed Stochastic Neighbor Embedding* approach.

It is very easy to implement and even provides an option to get the same output in every run of `tsne` with the same parameters - something that is absent in the `scikit` implementation.

It is a python wrapper for the original implementation by Laurens van der Maaten.

So basically you'll just need to do the following instead of the regular `TSNE` from `scikit` :

```
from bhtsne import tsne
data_nd_tsne = tsne(diff_df)
```